# Range of correlation

Tags: statistics, correlation

$A, B, X$ are random variables.

If we know $corr(A, X)=0.03, corr(B, X)=0.04, corr(A, B)=0$

What's the range of the correlation between an arbitrary linear combination of $A, B$ and $Y$
i.e. $corr(c_1A + c_2B, X)$?

I tried to simplify it by using $Cov(X, Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$ and rules of $Var()$ calculation, but I got an expression in which the range still seems unclear.

Comment: Better to start with $Cov(c_1A + c_2B, X)=c_1\,Cov(A , X)+c_2\,Cov(B, X)$

Comment: @Henry Yes, I have derived to this point. At last, I have the final correlation expression which has an term of $\sigma_B / \sigma_A$. I am stuck there to see a range.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit into your question how far you have got.  It will make a difference whether $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be negative

Comment: @Henry Please see my answer below, this is what I have got so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By using bilinerity formula of Cov, it shows that $$\rho = \frac{\rho_{A,X} c_1\sigma_A + \rho_{B,X} c_2\sigma_B}{\sqrt{c_1^2\sigma_A^2 + c_2^2\sigma_B^2}}$$ (derived by using $corr(A, B) = 0$), I can imagine this as to do projection of $(\rho_{AX}, \rho_{BX})$ into the direction of $(c_1, c_2)$ in the $\sigma_A, \sigma_B$ space. Since it could be any direction, the range shall be within range $$(-\sqrt{\rho_{A,X}^2 + \rho_{B,X}^2}, \sqrt{\rho_{A,X}^2 + \rho_{B,X}^2})$$ if we take $corr_a = 0.03, corr_b=0.04$, the range should be $(-0.05, 0.05)$. Not sure if this is the correct answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).